# Do Backbone where and findWhere return model by value or reference

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Does where() and findWhere() methods return the model itself in a collection or a copy of the model?
As I have read the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere) it does not explicitly and specifically notes the case.

First way, one can modify the returned result from it and use `set()` on it to add new attributes or change existing attributes' values directly without calling `add()` after `set()` them on the collection includes this model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone.js (and javascript in general) does everything by reference, so models will never be cloned unless explicitly done so. You can clone a model by calling `.clone()` on the model/collection, or by passing a Backbone.Model into another model constructor (`new Backbone.Model(model)`).

In Backbone, You can move models between collections, arrays, objects, anything and they won't get cloned along the way.

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/Lj3r85ew/

```
var origModel = new Backbone.Model({ id: 0 });

// where and findWhere return the model instance, not clones.
var collection = new Backbone.Collection([origModel]),
    where = collection.where({ id:0 })[0],
    findWhere = collection.findWhere({ id:0 });

where === origModel; // true
findWhere === origModel; // true
```

-

```
// Cloning a model
var copy1 = origModel.clone(),
    copy2 = new Backbone.Model(origModel.toJSON()),
    copy3 = new Backbone.Model(origModel);

copy1 === origModel; // false
copy2 === origModel; // false
copy3 === origModel; // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the where() and the findWhere() functions operate in a similar fashion to the respective underscore.js commands.

Both methods return a reference to the original object. `find` returns an array, while `findWhere` returns a single object (or `undefined`)